# How can i Update Add and Delete user address in Application using PUT http://Base URL/rest/V1/customers/me?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.4, customer-address

I am working on Magento -2.2.4. and working with REST API.

When The customers are having multiple addresses. When i am trying to update one address from list of existed addresses of the customer, The current updating address is updating fine. But, Remaining all existed addresses are deleted.

I followed this : https://www.ipragmatech.com/edit-delete-address-magento-mobile-app/

How can i update the customer's address with out deleting remaining addresses in application with magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formate of body to update delete and add address in magento rest API

```
{"customer":
  {"email": "test@test.com",
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastname": "test",
    "store_id": 13,
    "website_id": 5,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 84,
            "customer_id": 31,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "AP",
                "region": "Andhra Pradesh",
                "region_id": 555
            },
            "region_id": 534,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "test",
                "test",
                "test"
            ],
            "company": "test",
            "telephone": "1234567890",
            "postcode": "00000",
            "city": "test",
            "firstname": "test",
            "lastname": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 107,
            "customer_id": 31,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "test",
                "region": "test",
                "region_id": 0
            },
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "test",
                "test",
                "test"
            ],
            "company": "test",
            "telephone": "78944561230",
            "postcode": "00000",
            "city": "test",
            "firstname": "test",
            "lastname": "test"
        }
    ]
  }
 }
```